# Setting the Location of a Filestream using a string variable

Tags: c#, filestream

I want to create a program that will let me open a txt file in it and allow me to edit then save it. I am trying to set the directory of file to the selectedFile variable.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace TabControl
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string selectedFile;
        FileStream file = new FileStream(SELECTEDFILE, fileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write);
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnBack.Visible = true;
            tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
            btnSave.BringToFront();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnBack.Visible = false;
            tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            btnSave.SendToBack();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            txtDirectory.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            selectedFile = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to use selectedFile as the directory for file stream but the ways I have tried it are not working, how would I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Read .txt file into TextBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13900441/c-sharp-read-txt-file-into-textbox)

Comment: are you wanting the text of the file in `selectedFile`?

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz yes, I want to use it, but not just in the text box, I want to use it for other things later.

Comment: Then I think the answer linked to by @AlexK. is what you're needing.

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz It is, the way it was structured was - at first - a bit confusing, but I got it.

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13900441/c-sharp-read-txt-file-into-textbox).